# automatic wordpress core and plugin version monitoring to json file

Tags: wordpress

because of a lot of Wordpress Sites I have to maintain, I created a little function which generates a json file with the latest Core & Plugin Update informations. My monitor page than gets this json files via curl and displays them in a list.

The problem is, the data in the json file seems only to be actualized, after a backend login. I tried to use the init action to have it working without a backend login, but it doesn't.

Has someone an idea, how to fix it? I would like to get an actual state every 72 hours. Here is my function from functions.php:

```
function wpCheckUpdateState() {

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/version.json';

  // check only every 72 hours (259200sec)
  if( is_writeable($upload_dir['basedir']) && ( !is_readable($file) || filemtime($file) < time() - 259200) ) {

    if( function_exists('file_put_contents') ) {                

        $data['rebuild'] = false;

        if( get_site_transient('update_plugins') == false) {
            wp_update_plugins();
            $data['rebuild'] = true;
        }

        $plugins = get_site_transient( 'update_plugins' );

        $data['wp-version'] = get_bloginfo('version');
        $data['updated'] = date('d.m.y H:i', $plugins->last_checked);
        $data['plugins']['update'] = count($plugins->response);
        $data['plugins']['no_update'] = count($plugins->no_update);

        $json_data = json_encode($data);
        file_put_contents($file, $json_data);

    }

  }

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpCheckUpdateState' );
```

Comment: Run it as a [cronjob](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp-cron) (server activated, not wp default)

Comment: The problem isn't that this function isn't run every time, the problem is that the data isn't actualized. This happens only after a backend login. So I need some tipps to fix that. :)